# How to sum multiple values that are stored in a JSONb field on Rails 5.1 and PG

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, jsonb

I have a Rails application with a table named items: that contain a jsonb field with multiple values: item_weight1:, item_weight2, item_weight3, item_weight4, item_weight5... etc

Is there a way to sum all those values and display them in a view?

Is there a more efficient way to do this (store multiple values from a Form and display the sum of those values in a view)?

Please let me know if you need more details (code).

Thanks so much!

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using jsonb over json format?

Comment: I had the jsonb field for other values as well that are queried and joined to other tables. I just added a few more values to it like multiple item weights... Should I use JSON instead for those values, or should I approach it differently?

Comment: Not necessarily. I was just wondering why you chose to go that route. JSONB does have some advantages over JSON.

Comment: Try researching Postgres aggregate functions with Rails. There are an infitine number of resources out there that will help you out (specifically dealing with summing columns).

Comment: Can you post some data sample as input (query result) and expected output? I suppose you should manipulate the query result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's suppose your `jsonb` column is returned as a hash (if not, let us know), then you need to manipulate this has in order to sum the values.

You should check if

```
@item.jsonb_column.class # => Hash
```

I make an example guessing your data.

```
hash_from_jsonb_column = {"item_weight1": "10", "item_weight2": "10", "item_weight3": "10", "item_weight4": "10", "item_weight5": "10"}
```

One way to get the sum could be mapping values to an array of float:

```
sum = hash_from_jsonb_column.values.map(&:to_f).inject(:+) # => 50.0
```